# install clodufiy3.4 at ubuntu14.04 error occured

Tags: cloudify

I installed cloudify3.4 according to the cloudify DOCS. When I install the manager, and executed like this:

```
# cfy bootstrap --install-plugins -p openstack-manager-blueprint.yaml -i openstack-manager-blueprint-inputs.yaml
```

an error occurred:

`[ERROR] Bootstrap failed! (Workflow failed: Task failed 'neutron_plugin.floatingip.create' -> Expected exactly one object of type network with match {'name': u'178d7438-ca18-4df6-a5d0-dd11a53155a5'} but there are 0)`

I have already installed

- "cloudify_openstack_plugin-1.4-py27-none-linux_x86_64-centos-Core.wgn"
- "cloudify_openstack_plugin-1.4-py27-none-linux_x86_64-redhat-Maipo.wgn"

So, how to solve this error?
Thank you to everyone who helped me!

Answer (score 2):

In Cloudify version 3.4, the Cloudify manager can **only** be installed (bootstrapped) on either **CentOS 7.x** or **RHEL 7.x**.

See more details :

http://docs.getcloudify.org/3.4.0/manager/prerequisites/

**FYI**:  There are no limitations in host agents.
That means that once the Cloudify manager is alive, it will enable you to deploy anything on every operating system.